# What are the documents needed to visit a relative in Germany?

Tags: paperwork

I have a sister who has been a German citizen for more than 24 years. She  is planning to invite me to visit her and her family in Germany. What are the necessary documents I need from my country to be able to go there? Also, what are the documents that my sister needs?

Comment: Since you don't mention your citizenship, it is impossible to answer...

Answer (score 1):

- If you are from a country with visa-free entry (EU, EEA, many "Western" nations"), you need a valid passport and enough funds on hand to pay for your immediate expenses.
- If you are from a country that requires a visa, your application will have to show ties to your home nation and a stable financial situation which make it *credible* that you are a tourist. There is no need for a formal invitation if you can pay your own food and lodging. You would still mention your sister in your description of the itinerary and the premise of the trip.
- If your financial situation is such that you cannot afford the trip on your own, it may help your chances if your sister signs a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)), which is a promise to reimburse the German state for any costs if you should overstay your visa.